# Control Raspberry Pi GPIO from Android

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to develop an application on android to work as a screen for inputs data and these data will be processed to generate some interfaces after some amount of time. It is a sort of human-android interaction. During the processing I want the android to be connected to raspberry pi and instruct GPIOs to move a servos.

I would be grateful if i get any direction to walk through.

Comment: Please state your question, not tell us what you want to do. Which part are you having difficulty with? There are lots of examples on setting up a python web server and controlling GPIO with a REST API. As it is, though, your post is too broad

Comment: Thanks Cricket for your reply. In fact, my question is how to to connect an android app running on android device to raspberry pi in order to control its GPIO. Thanks.

Comment: Right. And I feel like I have seen said examples elsewhere. Asking for tutorials on StackOverflow is off-topic, unfortunately. 1) Learn to control GPIO using Python, for example 2) Learn a python web server 3) Learn to connect Android to a web server. All of those topics make your question quite broad. Hope you understand

Comment: Thanks a lot. I completely understand. Again, thanks for your help. I will try to check out your suggestions. 

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now (since December 2016) You can do it with [Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/pwmservo) on Raspberry Pi side.